# How to change eclipse console output color?

Tags: eclipse, console

I am running eclipse on Ubuntu 12.04 and I'd like to change console output color. I tried to edit it via Preferences>Run/Debug>Console>Background color but it doesn't work. Is there some other way to change?

Answer (score 11):

The Run/Debug>Console menu is correct. But you have to use the "Standard Out/Standard Error text color" buttons. (You can select different colors for standard output and for standard error). Here:

[image: Console text colors in Eclipse]

Also see the Eclipse documentation:
http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/run-debug/ref-console.htm

Comment: as I said, somehow it doesn't work. What I did at the end was create a new custom theme (.css) and running eclipse on it.
This helped a lot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569364/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-navigator-view-in-eclipse

Comment: You said you changed the *background* color. That wouldn't work :)

Comment: Hm, I have never seen these options before. How does Eclipse identity an error message in the compiler output?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye There are normally three "standard" streams that connect a program with its environment: stdin (standard input), stdout (standard output), and stderr (standard error). Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams. Java implements these streams in the class `System`, see the global fields in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html. In Eclipse, these streams are connected to the console, and the above configuration dialog allows you to select different colors for the different streams. The program itself decides what message goes to which stream.

Comment: In the case of the output from the *compiler* to which your question was referring, it's no different. The compiler is also a program. The compiler knows which of its messages is an error message and which message is not, and sends its messages to either stderr or stdout accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Window->Preferences=>Build->Console

Answer (score 1):

I related concept but useful if someone would like full color output on Eclipse's console.

Get an Eclipse extension called ANSI Escape in Console (Link below)
https://mihai-nita.net/2013/06/03/eclipse-plugin-ansi-in-console/

The site contains instructions on how to use it. With this plug in you can output in full color to the console by using standard ANSII escape codes for the output of multicolored text and backgrounds on the console.  These ANSI escape codes also work if you run your Java programs on the linux command line, but not on the windows command line.

Comment: also available in eclipse marketplace